# How can I see the complete widget tree In Widget Inspector? Flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-debug

I want to see all children of a given widget at one place so that I can better model my app. The issue is, I am unable to see all children of any given widget at once, neither in VSC nor in online DartDevTools.

I have to manually travel to that child and then it is being in this widget tree diagram.

Currently there are many children of `MaterialApp` widget but since I have only visited the 3 screens visible in screenshot it is only showing them and no other ones.  I couldn't find similar question and also didn't find any documentation regarding this. Any help is appreciated.

I am using `ChangeNotifierProvider` for state-management.

[image: current Widget Tree]

Comment: you can click on expand icon`>`

Comment: Actually the situation is that `MaterialApp` widget is having many children but  since I have only visited the above shown 3 screens it is only showing them and no other ones. Thanks for your consideration.